# How to find the longest consecutive sequence of numbers in a string array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sequence

Given a list in which each item is either the letter "I" (incomplete) or a number (completed), output the length of the longest sequence of complete passes. The list is preceded by the number of items. Given 8 4 15 9 I 30 2 I 20, the output is 3 (because the longest sequence of complete passes is 4 15 9).

I am able to find the correct number if the sequence is a mix of numbers and I's, but not if the sequence is only I's or only numbers.

```
int currSeq = 0;
int longestSeq = 0;
int lastIndex = 0;
boolean hasHit = false;

for (i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    currSeq = i - lastIndex;
    if (listItems[i].equals("I") && currSeq > longestSeq) {
        longestSeq = currSeq - (hasHit ? 1 : 0);
        lastIndex = i;
        hasHit = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: in the if you should also check if you are at the end of the array (`i==numItems-1`)

Comment: "The list is preceded by the number of items." - that means the leading 8 is not part of the list.

Comment: If you want a proper answer, you should post a [mcve]. How is `listItems` declared? Is it `Object[] listItems` ? Note that an [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) is not the same as a [list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html). Also, since this appears to be an assignment, are there any limitations? Can you use any part of the Java programming language to implement the requirements? Can you use any class or interface in the [JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/) ?

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static int findLongestConsecutiveNumberSequenceLength(Object[] items) {
    int res = 0;

    for (int i = 0, cur = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        cur = "I".equals(items[i]) ? 0 : cur + 1;
        res = Math.max(res, cur);
    }

    return res;
}
```